# Find substrings from first string in second String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search, substring

Update: I have two Strings.

```
  String a = "is am are has have was " //Helping verbs
  String b= " Robert and william are English Robert has a car he was living in England " //Sentence
```

update : pick first substring from String a then search for that substring in substrings of String b. If found, return index numbers of both. then continue to find first String's second subString in second String and so on till last .

Answer (score 4):

Please find the code below :-

```
        String stringA = "one two three four five six " ;
        String stringB = " eleven two four twelve thirteen ";


        String[] stringOne = stringA.split(" ");
        String[] stringTwo = stringB.trim().split(" ");

        Map<Integer,Integer> mapMatchingStrings = new HashMap<>();
        IntStream.range(0,stringOne.length).forEach(indexOfStringOne -> IntStream.range(0,stringTwo.length).forEach(indexOfStringTwo ->
                {
                 if(Objects.equals(stringOne[indexOfStringOne],stringTwo[indexOfStringTwo])){
                     mapMatchingStrings.put(indexOfStringOne,indexOfStringTwo);
                 }
                }
                ));
        System.out.println(mapMatchingStrings);
```

Output :-

> {1=1, 3=2}

Comment: FindHelpingVerbs(String[] a, String[] b){ Map<Integer,Integer> mapMatchingStrings = new HashMap<>();  IntStream
.range(0,a.length)
.forEach (indexOfStringOne -> IntStream
.range(0,b.length)
.forEach(indexOfStringTwo ->    {
 if (Objects
.equals(a[indexOfStringOne], b[indexOfStringTwo]))   {
 mapMatchingStrings
.put(indexOfStringOne,indexOfStringTwo);
 }
  }
));
System.out.println(mapMatchingStrings);
}        result: {} //blank , no result

Comment: are  you sending the same input as you did in the question?

Comment: if there is another input please send it to me.

Comment: yes the result i am getting by your code is {2=3, 3=6, 5=10}

Comment: is it the respone that you wanted?

Comment: run:
{2=3, 3=6, 5=10}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: these are all matches at once. i want this process one by one. when first substring from "string a" found in "string b" then get previous substring if found(exception: index 0 substring) and next substring and make relations in any datastructure like ast. if duplicates found they will merge into existing substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String a = "one two three four five six ";
    String b= " eleven two four twelve thirteen "  ;
           List<String> aSub =   Arrays.asList(a.split(" "));
           List<String> bSub =   Arrays.asList(b.split(" "));

    for(String s1 :aSub){
        for(String s2 :bSub){
            if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)){
            System.out.println( s1+" exists and is found in index "+ bSub.indexOf(s1));
        }
      }
    }
```

> result:
>
> two exists and is found in index 2
>
> four exists and is found in index 3

Comment: run:
are exists and is found in index 3
has exists and is found in index 6
was exists and is found in index 10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to split the string would be to use the StringTokenizer class

```
    String a = "one two three four five six";
    String b = "eleven two four twelve thirteen";
    StringTokenizer aT = new StringTokenizer(a," "/*delimiter(space or comma)*/);

    while (aT.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String indexA = aT.nextToken();
        StringTokenizer bT = new StringTokenizer(b," ");
        int index = 0;
        while(bT.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if(bT.nextToken().equals(indexA))System.out.println("Found Match:"+index);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Big O of N*N solution
class SubString{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
System.out.println(new SubString().getCommonSubString("abcdefg","zycdemm"));
}
public int getCommonSubString(String A, String B)
{
int ans =0;

     for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++)
     {
       int c=0;
       int k =i;
       for(int j=0;k<A.length()&&j<B.length();j++)
       {

         if(A.charAt(k)==B.charAt(j))
         {
           c++;
           ans = Math.max(ans, c);
           k++;
         }else
         {
           c=0;
           k=i;
         }
      }
    }
 return ans;
}
}
```

Comment: this code result: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 23
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)